# Automatically ctrl-w w to vimrc

Tags: vim

I recently started using NERDTree with vim, and have set it to automatically open with vim whenever I start it, however, the I would like the cursor to automatically move over to the window that is on the right whenever a file opens.

How can I have vim automatically execute the window toggle command (ctrl-w + w or l) when it starts?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add:

```
autocmd VimEnter * wincmd w
```